# Java Class cannot see changes made to static ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, arraylist, static

So I'm making a multi-threaded battleship server. In the server is a public static `ArrayList` that holds all of the different threads that are running. When the server is first instantiated, I add the first thread to the static `ArrayList`. The debugger displays this:

> myList    ArrayList  (id=17) size: 1

```
BattleshipServer temp = new BattleshipServer(32100);
threads.add(temp);
threads.get(threads.size()-1).start();
```

However, when the client tries to connect to the thread, I get an `OutOfBoundsException`.

```
serverSocket = new Socket(
        InetAddress.getByName(serverIpStrg),
        BattleshipServer
                .getThreads()
                .get(BattleshipServer.getThreads().size()-1)
                .SERVER_PORT
);
```

The debugger for the client says the `ArrayList` has a size:0

What is going on? How can I let the client see the `ArrayList` that the Server has?

Edit: Initialization of `Vector` (outside of constructor):

```
public volatile static Vector<BattleshipServer> threads =
        new Vector<BattleshipServer>();

/**
 * Creates a new battleship server
 */
public BattleshipServer(int port)  {
```

Constructor goes... `Vector` is never initialized again

Comment: Is the ArrayList thread safe? Synchronised?

Comment: @mbs Yes, I've put synchronize blocks around the code that accesses the ArrayList in the Server code

Comment: A couple of suggestions, try using Vector instead of ArrayList, as it is thread safe; are you sure the static variable is not being initialized again, between calls?

Comment: @AleZalazar I'll try using a Vector instead, and I only initialize the ArrayList/Vector once when it's declared as a class variable

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: I don't understand why the client has to know anything about the server's internals...You should have a known address to connect to, and then the server would accept the connection and launch another thread. Am I missing something?

Comment: @xp500 The client needs to know which port to use, which will change each time a new thread is launched. Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @AleZalazar I added the initialization of the threads vector

Comment: There should be a predefined port (or ports) and addresses where the server is listening and the client connects to one of those. Then, once the server receives a connection to one of those sockets the server accepts that connection and gets a socket that it will use to talk to the client and then launches the thread that will manage that connection

Comment: And I guess the first bit of code add the temp variable to BattleshipServer.getThreads()

Comment: Wait, is the client running in the same process as the server? Your wording is very confusing. A static variable is "application scoped" so to speak so a client will have no access to the servers memory hence it will always be size 0.